# Safari extension autoinstall

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I want to host an extension on my own website

When user clicks a specific button on my site, extension should install automatically just like it does from Apple - Safari - Extension section https://extensions.apple.com

Comment: That might not be possible, but you can just offer the extension binary (*.safariextz) on your site and users can download. I forget if system auto-detects the extension and prompts user if they want to install or if they have to manually install (double-click, or drag & drop to Safari, or open from Safari) to install it. But it's not that hard for users to do, you can just list the instructions for them to manually install after download.

Comment: It's true, but I wish I can make it easier

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. Inline installation of extensions from 3rd party websites is not available on Safari.

You can however just download the extension yourself and open it programmatically.

Or

You can ask the user to download the extension and double click the extension from the downloads folder. However if you take this route you will need to have some UI to educate the user.